# Symbol resolution when multiple versions of same library are used

Tags: c++, c, libcurl, ld, name-conflict

I have a solaris shared object (common.so file) that runs as part of a third party application(app.exe). I do not have access to the source code of the application. To the so, I need to add a capability to post http requests. My plan is to use libcurl with openssl. The tricky part is that app.exe already has a dependency on an older version of curl (7.14) which does not support ssl with tls v1.2.

I downloaded the source code and built curl (7.55.1) and openssl .a files. I was also able to build common.so with static dependency on these archive files. ldd does not show dependency on curl or ssl .so files and it also does not report any "Symbol not found" errors.

With this result, I was expecting my version of curl to be invoked when the so runs as part of the application but it did not. Instead curl_version() displays older version and I get the error unknown ssl protocol error

I am using solaris studio compiler. The application does not depend on curl libraries directly but depends on a different .so file which exports symbols with the same names as curl. I realized from nm and I am assuming that this .so file also links curl statically.

Comment: You say you don't have access to the source code of the application.  But can you at least rebuild or otherwise edit the binary to depend on a newer `libcurl`?  What platform is this on?

Comment: This is on solaris SunOS version 5.10. I cannot rebuild or edit the binary. I can use an external tool like objcopy and modify the symbols of that shared object externally but that may have some unintended consequences.

Answer (score 0):

When app.exe loads the two SO in question, it adds the functions of each to its symbol table. Now one of two possible scenarios *must* occur (which one actually is OS detail but irrelevant here...):

1. The newer version is loaded *before* the older version and the older one overwrites the newer one's entries.
2. The newer version is loaded *after* the older one, and as there are already entries in the table, it is not updated any more.

Now the cleanest solution – if applicable, i. e. if you have access to the sources – would be updating the other SO to use the newer version of curl. If doing so, consider creating curl as a new SO instead of linking it statically into both common.so and the other SO.

Otherwise, to solve the issue directly, you would have to switch the order the app loads the SO, which probaly would mean to decompile app.exe and rebuild it with the linkage order of the SO changed. Problem then: there might be two versions of app.exe around then, and you must make sure that only the correct one is distributed with your common.so. Potential source of trouble, too...

Apart from this, best I can think up is a workaround:

You might modify the curl prefix from `curl_` to e. g. `curl_755_`. Do not try this by hand, though, you most likely would go crazy this way... Use a script (e. g. perl or python) for instead. And if you ever update the curl sources, you can just run it again then...

Faster version, but potentially unsafe: just replace any occurences. Safer: Identify the externally visible functions (and possibly global objects) in a first run and keep them in a map, then replace any occurence of a string contained in the map with the corresponding value.

The latter approach (map) would additionally allow to generate macros in the header files of the following form:

```
#define curl_xyz curl_755_xyz
```

These macros allow the sources of common.so to just look like as if the original sources of curl were used...

Comment: Yeah :/ I've used this renaming trick to get around problems like this in the past, but it's horrible. You really need to change _everything_ -- every exported symbol -- or there could still be references to the old version. You could check this, I guess, by building a test program that links against the hacked version of libcurl, and doesn't reference the "real" (old) libcurl at all. But nasty, really nasty.

Comment: This is why the task should be done via some script. First, it saves a potentially tremendous amount of work, second, it can be called again on source update and third, if implemented correctly, is far more likely to catch all necessary occurences than doing doing things by hand... If being lucky, there even exists some script somewhere in the internet already...

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a try and let you know. Does it make any difference if I am linking statically with libcurl.a and not libcurl.so? I expected that when I link statically, common.so contains all the definitions it needs within itself and those will supersede any definitions from other dependent so files.

Comment: Well, yes, common.so will contain any definitions it needs, but which ones supersede (newer or older libcurl definitions) depends on the order app.exe loads the SO - and as you experienced already, these can as well be the older ones... On the other hand, you wouldn't have had this problem at all if *both* common.so and the other library were linked against libcurl.so. You could just have exchanged the so and *done* - provided, at least, the (used part of) libcurl interface did not change...